# Should I create a bootstrap-datepicker tag and retag relevant questions with it?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

At the moment, we have [probably over 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap+datepicker) questions related to the [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) library, but until now, we had no specific tag for it. Instead, people would generally tag questions about the library with [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) and [datepicker](/questions/tagged/datepicker).

It seems to me that creating a tag specific to the library would be helpful, since:

- Having a specific tag for the library would make it possible for people familiar with the library to add it to their favorite tags and see questions about it in their question feed, without having the add the highly generic [datepicker](/questions/tagged/datepicker) tag.
- It would also remove ambiguity in cases where someone is using both Twitter's bootstrap library and some kind of datepicker *other* than bootstrap-datepicker, like [jquery-ui-datepicker](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-datepicker) or a datepicker they've made themselves.

This seems like a clearly good idea to me, and I've already [made a start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-datepicker) on the retagging. But I've never embarked on any kind of large-scale retagging before, and am a little nervous about whether I'm doing the right thing. Given the number of questions I'm going to be messing with if I embark on this, I figure I should ask first: is what I'm doing sensible?

Comment: I was once told by a mod that retagging is bad unless it is *really* required (Since it bumps questions to the front page)

Comment: Not sure if the second point holds. If someone is asking about using bootstrap with a different picker, they'd probably be more likely to click [bootstrap-datepicker] if they saw it as an auto-suggest when typing bootstrap.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName You really think that? Our judgements on this vary dramatically; I think it's reasonably unlikely that the case you've described will *ever* happen, let alone happen frequently - even without reading the tag excerpt, I think it'll be reasonably clear that `bootstrap-datepicker` refers to a particular library. I certainly think it's *much* less likely than an answerer seeing a question tagged with `jQuery`, `bootstrap` and `datepicker` and wrongly assuming that the question is about `jquery-ui-datepicker` instead of `bootstrap-datepicker`, which I've seen happen already.

Comment: You may be right, I'm just going by what I've seen happen with android-datepicker. A lot of the questions have nothing to do with the date picker that's part of the API, but whatever date picker they happen to be using.